# Is it possible to omit specific files from BitBucket pull request?

Tags: ruby, git, bitbucket, pull-request

We are a large team that uses Pull Requests for Code Review and more in a daily routine. Sometimes, the Pull Requests gets too big, making it impossible to open some files on load.

[image]

There are some files inside the commits (like [vcr cassette](https://github.com/vcr/vcr)) that could be excluded from the Pull Request, since they are generated automatically and it is pointless to review this code.

The question is: how can I omit files in my BitBucket's Pull Requests?

I know we could let those files be pushed only after the approval of the Pull Request, but this could lead to some mistakes. Any other approach is welcome.

Comment: Can you not add those auto-generated files to the .gitignore list?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Without those files the system will not work correctly, so I still need them.

Comment: But if they're auto-generated, do you really need to keep tracking them when they should be recreated when you run the app the next time, or during testing?

Comment: They are automatically generated on the first run of the tests, and are necessary to keep they working. Sorry if I was not clear before.